# MySQL - Finding Gaps of Date Ranges - Overlapping Dates

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have been struggling for a long time with generating gaps in date ranges, according to a set.

```
CREATE TABLE `terms` (
  `id` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `term_begin` date NOT NULL,
  `term_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `term_served` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `office_type_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `removal_reason_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `political_party_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_elected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_holdover` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `neat_race_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `office_class` int NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_vacant` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `terms` (`id`, `term_begin`, `term_end`, `term_served`, `office_type_id`, `person_id`, `state_id`, `district_id`, `removal_reason_id`, `political_party_id`, `is_elected`, `is_holdover`, `neat_race_id`, `office_class`, `notes`, `is_vacant`) VALUES
(2, '2005-01-03', '2011-01-04', NULL, 1, 3, 2, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, 0, '2004-11-02~WA~S', 3, 'S', NULL),
(44, '2007-01-04', '2013-01-02', NULL, 1, 96, 2, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, 0, '2006-11-07~WA~S', 1, 'S', NULL),
(113, '2011-01-05', NULL, NULL, 1, 3, 2, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, 0, '2010-11-02~WA~S', 3, 'S', NULL),
(147, '2013-01-03', NULL, NULL, 1, 96, 2, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, 0, '2012-11-06~WA~S', 1, 'S', NULL),
(250, '2001-01-03', '2007-01-03', NULL, 1, 96, 2, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, NULL, '2000-11-07~WA~S', 1, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO `terms` (`id`, `term_begin`, `term_end`, `term_served`, `office_type_id`, `person_id`, `state_id`, `district_id`, `removal_reason_id`, `political_party_id`, `is_elected`, `is_holdover`, `neat_race_id`, `office_class`, `notes`, `is_vacant`) VALUES
(26, '2005-01-03', '2011-01-04', NULL, 1, 57, 26, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, 0, '2004-11-02~MO~S', 3, 'S', NULL),
(129, '2011-01-05', NULL, NULL, 1, 262, 26, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, 0, '2010-11-02~MO~S', 3, 'S', NULL),
(61, '2007-01-04', '2013-01-02', NULL, 1, 133, 26, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, 0, '2006-11-07~MO~S', 1, 'S', NULL),
(154, '2013-01-03', NULL, NULL, 1, 133, 26, NULL, NULL, 10001, 1, 0, '2012-11-06~MO~S', 1, 'S', NULL),
(218, '2003-01-03', '2009-01-05', NULL, 1, 134, 26, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, NULL, '2002-11-05~MO~S', 1, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO `terms` (`id`, `term_begin`, `term_end`, `term_served`, `office_type_id`, `person_id`, `state_id`, `district_id`, `removal_reason_id`, `political_party_id`, `is_elected`, `is_holdover`, `neat_race_id`, `office_class`, `notes`, `is_vacant`) VALUES
(24, '2005-01-03', '2011-01-04', NULL, 1, 53, 24, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, 0, '2004-11-02~GA~S', 3, 'S', NULL),
(124, '2011-01-05', NULL, NULL, 1, 53, 24, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, 0, '2010-11-02~GA~S', 3, 'S', NULL),
(183, '2015-01-06', NULL, NULL, 1, 345, 24, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, 0, '2014-11-04~GA~S', 2, 'S', NULL),
(208, '2003-01-03', '2015-01-05', NULL, 1, 193, 24, NULL, NULL, 10000, 1, NULL, '2002-11-05~GA~S', 2, NULL, NULL);
```

### THE GOAL

For every grouping of (office_type_id, state_id, district_id, office_class)

find the `term_end` of the term, preceding another term (with same above group), as well as the `term_begin` of the succeeding term.

This will = the date range for which no records are logged

Every data chunk, has the same state as the other rows in the chunk, differentiated by office class

### first chunk, has no gaps, and no overlaps (dates are for office class 1)

`2001-01-03` -> `2007-01-03`
`2007-01-04` -> `2013-01-02`
`2013-01-03` -> `NULL`

### Second Chunk, has no gaps, but has overlaps (dates are for office class 1)

`2003-01-03` -> `2009-01-05`
`2007-01-04` -> `2013-01-02`     (overlaps with above)
`2013-01-03` ->  `NULL`

### Third Chunk, has gap  (office class 2)

`2003-01-03` -> `2009-01-05`
`2015-01-06` -> `Null`)

`gap = 2009-01-05 -> 2015-01-06`

This database grows forward. District_id can be null, but the otehr values can not be (state_id, office_type_id, office_class)

My attempts have largely been failing. A fiddle is created here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d19/22

I am first trying to merge the overlaps, and (add 1 day to term_end to make all regular 1 day gaps ignored).

This does not work. You see for state_id = 2 and office_class - 1, there are two rows.

I would imagine this should merge as `2001-01-03` ->  `Null`

The merge is just the **first step** of the process I am trying to accomplish.

> I am trying to find **date ranges** for which the **office_type,
>   office_class, state, district** does not have term data

I am at a complete loss for this. I have been trying for a week now. I have a variety of other versions of queries to post as well if requested.

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
[office_type_id ] [ state_id ] [district_id] [office_class] [FROM] [TO]

1                    24            NULL      2     '2009-01-05'  '2015-01-06'
```

The above means, that no a term exists from ... -> '2009-01-05'. and from '2015-01-06' -> ....   but no term exists between the two.

Comment: @Busturdust You say that `district_id` can be null, but nothing else. Why are those columns marked as `DEFAULT NULL`, instead of `NOT NULL` then?

Comment: I meant as criteria of the groups... out of the 4 pertinent fields (office_type_id, state_id, district_id, office_class).... only district  can be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If overlaps are only partial, (i.e., a range may partially overlap another, but no range is a subset of another range), I think the following query will do what you want:

```
SELECT t1.office_type_id, t1.state_id, t1.district_id, t1.office_class,
        t1.term_end, MIN(t2.term_begin) next_begin
FROM terms t1 JOIN terms t2  
  ON t1.office_type_id=t2.office_type_id AND 
     t1.state_id=t2.state_id AND 
     (t1.district_id=t2.district_id OR 
       (t1.district_id IS NULL AND t2.district_id IS NULL)) AND 
     t1.office_class=t2.office_class 
WHERE t1.term_begin < t2.term_begin 
GROUP BY t1.office_type_id, t1.state_id, t1.district_id, t1.office_class, 
         t1.term_end 
HAVING t1.term_end < next_begin - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

If ranges may fully overlap, I suggest to create a view that removes such subranges:

```
CREATE VIEW terms1 AS
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM terms t3 
WHERE (office_type_id, state_id, office_class) NOT IN
     (SELECT office_type_id, state_id, office_class FROM terms t4 
      WHERE ((t4.term_begin < t3.term_begin AND t3.term_end <=t4.term_end) OR 
             (t4.term_begin = t3.term_begin AND t3.term_end < t4.term_end)) 
        AND (t3.district_id = t4.district_id OR 
             (t3.district_id IS NULL and t4.district_id IS NULL)));
```

Then you can use this view instead of the table in the query above.

(And life would have been a bit simpler if you had picked some other value than NULL for the default district_id).